# Issue with search with Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am making a Rails 4 application that is a blog and I would like to have the ability on the site to search the titles of the posts. I am using the find method to "search" the titles of the posts and the show method to display the result. No matter what, not found is displayed.

```
def find
  @params = params[:post]
  title = @params[:title]
  @post = Post.find_by_title(@params[:title])
  respond_to do |format|
  if @title != nil
    format.html {render :action => :show}
  else
    format.html { render :action => :not_found }  
  end
end
end



def show
id = params[:item][:id]
    @post = Post.find_by_title(@params[:title])


respond_to do |format|
  if @post != nil
    format.html
  else
    format.html{render :action => "not_found"}
  end
end
end
```

Here is the HTML for the search

```
<h2>Find a post</h2>
<h3><%= form_for  :post, :url => {:action => :find} do |form| %>
<p><label for="title">Name:</label>
<%= form.text_field  :title, :size => 20 %></p>
<p><%= submit_tag   "Find a Post" %></p></h3>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Side comment: your solution only finds exact matches. If you want more hits you can do `Post.where 'title like ?', "%#{@params[:title]}%"`

Answer (score 1):

"Not found" is displayed because your `if @title != nil` is always going to fail because `@title` is always nil as you've not defined it.

You need to do:

```
def find
  @params = params[:post]
  @title = @params[:title]  # <--------- here set `title` to `@title`
  @post = Post.find_by_title(@params[:title])
  respond_to do |format|
  if @title != nil
    format.html {render :action => :show}
  else
    format.html { render :action => :not_found }  
  end
end
end
```

Also note that dynamic finders such as `find_by_title` are deprecated in Rails 4.  You should replace them with `where`.  For example for `@post = Post.find_by_title(@params[:title])` you'd write `@post = Post.where(title: @params[:title])`

Answer (score 0):

Also, just out of curiosity, if you allow me: on your `show` method, you seem to have the ID in the params. Why don't you just retrieve the object by it's ID, using `@post = Post.find(params[:title][:id])`? Sorry for the unrequested tip =]